# JQuery Ajax Date Parse Issues

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

Hello so I am displaying a table with data in ASP.NET MVC using jQuery Ajax and initially my date output was `Date(1665774000000)`.

And after parsing, I get an error:

> Invalid Date

```
"<td>" + new Date(parseInt(GetSTTList[i].RequiredVisitDate)).toDateString() + "</td>"
```

Then I tried `substr(6)` and it showed `Sat Oct 15 2022`

```
"<td>" + new Date(parseInt(GetSTTList[i].RequiredVisitDate.substr(6))).toDateString() + "</td>"
```

How can I get the date in `15-Oct-2022` format?

My controller has

```
RequiredVisitDate = x.RequiredVisitDate,
```

Answer (score 0):

Key things that 1665774000000 is an epoch date in milliseconds

so oin c# you can convert that to a date using  DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeMilliseconds and then you can use a normal toString('dd-MMM-yyyy')

```
var dt = DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeMilliseconds(1665774000000);
    
Console.WriteLine(dt.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy"));
```

see https://dotnetfiddle.net/srx9kM

if its JS client side formatting then use

```
var date = new Date(1665774000000);
var resultFormat = date.toDateString()
```

OR

use Moment.js for client side Date handling https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/

```
moment(1665774000000).format('DD-MM-YYYY');
```

I recommend for JS Date handling, they've done all the hard work for you.  Stand on the shoulders of giants.